# Looking for a way to replace every instance of a non-zero sized file in a directory tree using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-command-prompt, batch

I am trying to figure out a way to have a batch script overwrite every instance of a non-zero byte file inside of a specific directory and its sub-folders. I'm guessing since I'm looking for a non-zero file I could probably loop it with a escape if it doesn't find any non-zero sized file?

Example, overwrite every instance of example.txt where it is a non-zero filesize:

```
D:\
\---SubFolder1
    |   example.txt <10 bytes>
    |
    \---Subfolder2
        |   example.txt <0 bytes>
        |
        \---Subsubfolder1
                example.txt <20 bytes>
```

In the example, D:\Subfolder1\example.txt, and D:\Subfolder2\Subsubfolder1\example.txt would be overwritten, but D:\Subfolder2\example.txt wouldn't be changed.

Thank you to @NiKiZe for all your help!

## Working Code:

> @ECHO OFF
>
> SET DPATH=%~dp0
>
> FOR /R "%DPATH%" %%F IN (****** SEE BELOW***) DO IF %%~zF <del>GTR</del> **NEQ** 0 CALL :NonEmptyFile "%%~F"
> GOTO :EOF
>
> :NonEmptyFile
> ECHO Got non empty file: %1
> <del>CALL :EOF</del>

*** Replace with filename that you are wanting to replace, be sure to use a single character wildcard somewhere (I used it in the extension - for example, if I am searching for example.txt, I replaced the * with example.t?t)

Comment: Does it have to be `cmd` ? You will have to do loops and recursive calls, but internal `for` should be able to do this.

Comment: I was wrong on the recursive calls things, at least from what I understand from the question, but might be wrong? Maybe it should only check for "example.txt"?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, I'm looking to add this to an existing batch file, where I need to replace existing files that have been updated (non-zero size) with the original 0 byte size file, and the file exists in multiple subfolders that can change, so I can't just hardcode every possible (sub)folder to just wipe and restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal batch that walks a given path and all subfiles and subpaths, calling the `NonEmptyFile` label for every non empty file.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET DPATH=%~dp0

FOR /R "%DPATH%" %%F IN (*) DO IF %%~zF GTR 0 CALL :NonEmptyFile "%%~F"
GOTO :EOF

:NonEmptyFile
  ECHO Got non empty file: %1
CALL :EOF
```

By using `%~1` in the function it will be expanded and you can use something like `COPY /Y "somefile.txt" "%~1"`
How you want to overwrite the files was not specified.

Another option to create "empty files" is `ECHO. > "%~1"`

##### Explanation:

- `FOR /R "%DPATH%" %%F IN (*) DO` walks every file
- `IF %%~zF GTR 0` if file size is greater than ...
- `CALL :NonEmptyFile "%%~F"` Call the `:NonEmptyFile` label with the filename escaped

To test this at prompt, use `FOR /R "D:\SubFolder1\" %F IN (*) DO IF %~zF GTR 0 ECHO NonEmptyFile "%~F"`

More info on how `for` works is given by running `for /?` in `cmd`

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to make a few tweaks to get it to cooperate, but this gave me a very good starting point!